# Bypassing Android Invensense Motion Library to create custom magnetometer calibration

Tags: android-ndk, sensors, compass-geolocation, magnetometer

I am looking to get the raw values from the magnetometer chips, Raw as in uncalibrated, unaltered, straight from the I2C interface.  I've traced down the android java, native source and invensense code API to the HAL and found that for the Galaxy Nexus (which uses the Yamaha GMR magnetometer) invensense applies an "adaptive filter", a threshold filter (dead zone), then performs a realtime magnetometer calibration to compensate for hard and soft iron biases.  I would like to bypass that calibration algorithm and replace it with my own.

Is there a way to intercept the magnetometer data after the serial comm code but before the calibration?  Can you access the invensense libraries through Android NDK?

Currently developing on :
- Galaxy Nexus
- Android 4.0 ICS
- Eclipse IDE, windows environment

Answer (score 0):

You can change the kernel driver to print those raw values directly.

Comment: Considering additional details or adding an example to make your answer more clear.